# Control Music From Notifcations Bar

Tags: ios, music.app

Using iOS6 is there a way to show or display music controls inside the notifications bar for quick access?

Note: I am looking for a native way to do this. If there is not a way I would welcome 3rd party apps that do this function, however, I prefer the standard music player and do not want to change the music player.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no built in way to do this with iOS 6 (or lower).

There are other ways to control music playback that may function as a work around for you.

1. If the device is unlocked, double tap the home button and swipe the row of apps *from* left to right. This will display Play/Pause controls. Swipe one more time - on an iPhone or iPod Touch - for volume control.
2. If the device is locked, double tap the home button. This will display music controls.

Comment: I was aware of the lock screen controls. I was not aware of the first. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this natively. There may be a third party app, but I don't know about it. You will probably need to jailbreak to achieve this functionality.